# I am working on a project in which I have to transfer data like names and values from one activity

Tags: java, android

I am working on a project in which I have to transfer data like names and values from one activity and it would be displayed on a textview of another activity, but everytime I do this the initial value of these variables get displayed instead of the current value which is being updated on the Java class activity please note that this is on android studio and I am just an upcoming programmer please be lenient.

I have used set and get static methods and intents and bundle but it's still displaying the initial value instead of the current value

here is the code

```
package com.example.android.bmi;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
private String name;
private int year;
private double BMI;
public String Diag;   
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);}
public void setName(){ 
   EditText nameF = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.name); 
    name = nameF.getText().toString();
}
public String getName() {    return name;}
public void setYear(){   
 EditText yearF = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.year); 
   String value = yearF.getText().toString(); 
   year = Integer.parseInt(value);
}
public void setAge() {    age = 2018 - year;}
public void setBMI(){    
EditText heightF = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.height);  
  String value = heightF.getText().toString(); 
   height = Integer.parseInt(value); 
   EditText weightF = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.weight); 
   String value1 = weightF.getText().toString(); 
   weight = Integer.parseInt(value); 
   BMI = (weight*567)/(height*height);
}
public String getDiag(){ 
   Diag = "Name: " + name;  
  Diag += "\nYear of Birth: " + year; 
   Diag += "\nAge: " + age; 
   Diag += "\nBMI" + BMI; 
   return Diag;
}public void mainN(View view) {   
 String bread = getDiag(); 
   Bundle basket = new Bundle(); 
   basket.putString("key", bread);  
  Intent a = new Intent(Main2Activity.this, Main3Activity.class);    a.putExtras(basket);
    startActivity(a);
}}
```

and the receiving Activity is

```
package com.example.android.bmicalculator;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Main3Activity extends AppCompatActivity {


String display;  
  @Override  
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main3);    
    TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.info);  
      Bundle gotBasket = getIntent().getExtras();  
      display = gotBasket.getString("key");  
      tv.setText(display);    }
```

Comment: Please add Your code.

Comment: Please add your code so that we can help.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please add more information about what you already tried (code snippets are the best)

Comment: You need to actually get the values **from** the edit text, not keep them in "stale" fields... If you really want dynamic fields for when you're typing in a form, lookup Android data binding

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you need help **passing data** from **one activity to another**.

In your **sender** activity, use the following code when starting the other activity -

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, NewActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("NAME", name);
intent.putExtra("VALUE", value);
startActivity(intent);
```

Here, `"NAME"` and `"VALUE"` are String constants used to identify the data you are sending and `name` and `value`are variables of the desired type (see [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#public-methods) for the list of `putExtra()` methods).

Now, in your receiving activity, where you want to get the data. Use methods like `getIntent().getStringExtra(String name);` to get a String or `getIntent().getIntExtra(String name, int defaultValue);` to get an int (other available methods are listed [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#public-methods)). For example.

```
String name = getIntent().getStringExtra("NAME");
int value = getIntent().getIntExtra("VALUE",0);
textView.setText(name);
```

Next time when asking a question, try doing the task yourself, and add in the question, what you have already tried and some relevant code to help us understand your problem.

Comment: I am sorry for not adding the code the first time like I said I am new at this programming

Comment: @wizsab that's fine. Format your code with 4 spaces. If this answered your question, please accept it as the answer

Comment: I have formatted the code but it is still not responding

Comment: @wizsab What is not responding? I see that you have used bundles in your code to pass the data. Did you try it directly with the intent as I have shown in my answer?

Comment: Also, you are not fetching the fresh values from the EditText when switching activities. Fetch the text using ((EditText) `findViewById(R.id.EDITTEXTIDHERE)).getText().toString();` when passing the intent to fetch the updated values.